# Android - send parameter to php script to use it in query

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

In my app data is fetched from a database. For that a variable is passed to a php script and should be used in the query later. I tried it using `$var = $_POST['name']` in the query, but it seems like the passed variable is empty.
To test it, I inserted the variable into a table and used the `isset()` method as well. The first part works as it should, the variable is set and inserted, but in the second part with the query to fetch the data it doesn’t seem to be set since the variable returns the value „a“. Why is the value not set and not taken from above?

The php code:

```
<?php

include Connection.php;



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if(isset($_POST['name'])){

 $query = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('$_POST[name]')";


 if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){

    echo 'Data Submit Successfully';

 }
 else{

    echo 'Try Again';

 }
}



if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
    $var = "a";
} 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$var'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $array[] = $row;
        }



    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: change `"INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('$_POST[name]')"` to `"INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ($_POST['name'])"`

Comment: @UmerFarooq Sorry for unprecise questioning, I tried to improve it. The problem I have is in the fetching part, my bad!

Comment: have you tried query without variable i mean `"SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = 'a'"`

Comment: @UmerFarooq yes I tried that and that works as it should do as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query string is incorrect, fix by this:

```
//...
$query = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."')";
//...
```

To fix `SELECT` query you should initialize $var in case `isset($_POST['name'])` returns true

```
//...
$var = "a";
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $var = $_POST['name'];
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$var'";
```

Comment: The inserting works this way, is it wrong or unconventional?

Comment: @MikeKng string can't parse array with key expression, you need to do it with a help of string concatenation or with a help of additional variable. `('".$_POST['name']."')";` or `$var = $_POST['name']; $query = "INSERT INTO TestTable (name) VALUES ('$var')";`

Answer (score 2):

In the code

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
    $var = "a";
} 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$var'";
```

change this to

```
$var = "";

if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
    $var = "a";
} 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE name = '$var'";
```

Comment: Isn‘t `$var` just empty then?

Comment: No..when `!isset($_POST['name'])` gets true, its value will set to 'a'. `$var` must be declared outside the scope of `if block` so that you can access it out side the scope of `if block`.

Comment: Since your `select query` is outside the `if block` therefore `$var` must be declared outside the scope of `if block` otherwise you can't access `$var` in your query

Comment: I understand, but `$_POST['name']` is used above as well, why does the `isset()` return that it‘s empty?

Comment: have you tried debugging the script by calling `var_dump($_POST)` before calling `isset()`. ?

Comment: I tried to but I’m not confident with debugging a script actually

Comment: @MikeKng  I think there is some problem in your java code.  Make sure that you are sending `post` parameters' properly. The reason `$_POST['name']` is empty is because `name` parameter is not sent from your java code.

Comment: I thought of that too, but why would it insert the right string I give it into the table otherwise?

Comment: @MikeKng  So what you get when you declared `$var` out of the scope of `if block' ?